# Strange Windows 10 Behavior

Tags: windows-10, avast

I just got back home from being away for a few hours. I usually sleep my computer (hardly ever turn it off). For reference, I use Avast Anti-Virus. When I hit the wake button and logged in I noticed that the Start Menu was open and that the "Life At a Glance" & "Play and Explore" panes were flickering.

Thought that was weird and it wouldn't stop so I rebooted. Now things really got strange.

Firstly I noticed a weird looking avast anti-virus desktop icon I had never seen before (not their typical logo icon) and an "avast safe browser" (never heard or used it before). I also noticed that Avast would not turn on active protection. Every time I tried to get it to turn on it the program seemed to just hang there not doing anything. I then noticed a Windows Defender icon in the system tray. Weird again because I don't ever remember enabling windows defender.

I disabled all windows defender options I could and then repaired avast. Seemed to repair fine. Rebooted the computer and things *seem* to be back to normal.

I'm just wondering what would have caused the weird avast icon and the safe browser icon to show up on my desk. And why would windows defender enable itself after over a year of successful error free use of Avast?

Any way this could have been some weird virus?

Answer (score 1):

This happend to me a couple of times before.

I just threw everything important onto a 5TB External HDD, Factory Reset the System, made a clean install of Windows and put everything back and installed everything that was on the computer before. You can make it 99% identical if you need to

I don't have any "faster" solution, but since no one else have answered, i just thought i would share my technique

Hope it works out for you

Comment: You couldn't restore the system to how it was just disabling Windows Defender and re-enabling your anti-virus and a reboot? Or you did it because you are suspicious it could be malicious?